# Are the level prerequisites for warlock invocations your total multiclass character level?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, multi-classing, character-levels, eldritch-invocations

If I was playing a character (class) 8/warlock 1, and then I put another level into warlock, would I be able to take the Sculptor of Flesh invocation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you would not

> **Sculptor of Flesh**
> Prerequisite: 7th level
>
> You can cast polymorph once using a warlock spell slot. You can’t do so again until you finish a long rest.

You would need to be at least a 7th level Warlock. The character level does not matter for the prerequisite.

As stated on PHB pg. 110

> **Eldritch Invocations**
>
> If an eldritch invocation has prerequisites, you must meet them to learn it. You can learn the invocation at the same time that you meet its prerequisites. A level prerequisite refers to your level in this class.

A 2018 Errata has been added to the Eldritch Invocations section stating:

> A level prerequisite refers to your level in this class.

Comment: The change was made in the [very first PHB errata in 2015](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/Errata_PH.pdf) (as noted by MivaScott's answer); it wasn't new to the [2018 PHB errata](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf).

Comment: @V2Blast Look at the wording in both errata. The 2015 only changed the intent. The 2018 changed the RAW.

Comment: ...No. The 2018 errata does not mark that change as "[New]" - all that's different about the 2018 errata is that it directly quotes changes instead of trying to summarize them as previous errata PDFs did (and often doing so inaccurately - see my "special mentions" in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/150622/33569) about undocumented changes in the 2018 printings). Feel free to check literally any printing of the PHB between 2015 and 2018 and you'll find identical wording to that quoted in the 2018 PHB errata.

Answer (score 9):

## No; invocation prerequisites are based on warlock level.

Eldritch Invocations are based on your Warlock level, not your character level. Per the [description](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations-388) (PHB, 110):

> If an eldritch invocation has prerequisites, you must meet them to learn it. You can learn the invocation at the same time that you meet its prerequisites. **A level prerequisite refers to your level in this class.**

The bolded sentence was added in [the 2015 PHB errata](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/Errata_PH.pdf).