# What are the size restrictions of a Clone (from spell)?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, creature-size

Some other players of 5e D&D have suggested that the *Clone* spell only works with a *Medium* size body. Putting this into perspective (and putting aside *obvious yet possibly reasonable discrimination* against creatures such as gnomes, kobolds and halflings), what is the actual RAW on this?

**Question:** *What living creatures can be cloned by the 8th level Clone spell - from what micro-minimum to what absolute maximum in size could this thing be?*

Answer (score 8):

### A creature can be cloned; the 'medium' size looks like a limitation

Clone's spell description says this:

> Components: V, S, M (a diamond worth at least 1,000 gp and at least 1 cubic inch of flesh of the creature that is to be cloned, which the spell consumes, and a vessel worth at least 2,000 gp that has a sealable lid and *is large enough to hold a Medium creature*, such as a huge urn, coffin, mud-filled cyst in the ground, or crystal container filled with salt water)

And, it says this.

> This spell grows an inert duplicate of a living creature as a safeguard against death.

But the [2018 errata says this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/150622/36521):

> [This spell grows an inert duplicate of a living, Medium creature as a safeguard against death](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/clone).

And who wants to clone gnomes, anyway?  8^p

#### Korvin's ruling as a DM?

I'd let a halfling or gnome PC have a clone; it would fit - but only if they player bought pizza for the next session!  8^D

#### Something that might work ...

If you cast the second level spell *enlarge/reduce* on the creature in question, and then use *wish* to cast *clone* (which avoids the need for spell components) you can probably make it work for a Small or Large creature.

> You don’t need to meet any requirements in that spell, including
>   costly Components. The spell simply takes effect.(wish, PHB)

As for what size the clone ends up being - that could be an interesting surprise. (thanks to @ RedOrca)

Comment: @Mecix Oops, not near my errata thing, thanks for the catch.

Comment: Oh you're good the errata doesn't even mention this change, it's... unfortunate at best

Comment: If you cast *enlarge/reduce* on yourself, then use *wish* to dupe *clone*, you can probably make it work for a Small or Large creature. As for what size the clone ends up being...?

Comment: @RedOrca I think you have the germ of a very nice stand alone question right there. :-)

Comment: Due to the material components requiring a *Medium* (note the capital M there), it must only work on [spiritual Mediums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediumship). We can thank [Terry Pratchett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terry_Pratchett) for his insight on this sort of thing. In all seriousness: thanks to everyone - read it twice. I am, indeed, half blind.

Comment: You highlight the text "_is large enough to hold a Medium creature_" - to me, I read that as "up to Medium" rather than "only Medium", because if something is large enough to hold medium creature, it's also large enough to hold a small creature (maybe two) or a (or many) tiny creature(s). However, clearly a large creature would not fit into something that is "large enough for a Medium creature". At least, that's my reading on this. Of course, that errata then ruins everything, which is why some people ignore the errata when it makes the rules make _less_ sense (see also: Ranger's Multiattack)!

Comment: In other words, your ruling (which I totally agree with) seems to fit how it was _originally_ written, the way I read it. +1 either way :)

Comment: @NathanS yeah, that errata is an odd thing, given that gnomes are a nice fit for Wizard (my brother has played 2 wizard gnomes in 5e).  I think "Up To" medium would fit nicely

Comment: [The latest errata](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) removed all instances of "Medium" from the spell

Answer (score 0):

Pushing this as deeply into *ad absurdum* and *slippery slope* territory as possible:

The smallest possible limit must be for the basic RAW *Clone* spell should be: any creature with less 'flesh' than a cubic inch, i.e. the amount required for the base-component to cast the spell. This requirement could be vetoed by any creature able to cast this without use of material components, such as the 5e D&D spell-casting dragon variant of CR24+. Such component-free castings would be able to duplicate one bacteria cell or possibly a virus... [were they considered a life-form](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/are-viruses-alive-2004/).

The largest size possible aught to include ANY living creature, as per RAW / spell description. Thus, the 'Garden of Eve with teeth and claws' planet for the Na'vi, [Pandora](https://james-camerons-avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Pandora) seems both alive (and even sentient). Granted, it may be tough to find a crystal container big enough, but once again, casters not requiring components can even do this casting quite easily. Those using [Wish](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Wish#content) spell can create duplicate living planets as a move action, once a day, without threat of exhaustion or other such reprimand-repercussion.

*'Look ma, a new planet just came into orbit!'* This would also be ideal if one had something like a living plane of existence or even living magic items. If a magic item is made from a fae, fiend, celestial or elemental, are they alive? Would such a *Clone* rebuild this magic item as a 'body'? This would be stuff for other questions and *Exchanges of Stack*.

Lore wise, this would explain why the Abyss is notoriously infinite: someone figured out how to replicate living planes for their homestead. It may be that the Abyss is a cloned wasteland created by one otherwise-bored ancient dragon, casting this as many times as he or she has in charisma modifier points.

Comment: Are you aware that the spell states that the creature must be medium-sized? ([source](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/clone)) "This spell grows an inert duplicate of a living, **Medium** creature as a safeguard against death." Note that this is not mentioned in the errata but is gone over [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/150622/36521).

Comment: @Medix2 reread the spell from the paper Players Handbook... twice! Dammit. And it specifies *Medium*, with a capital letter. That MUST mean it has to be a [spiritual Medium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediumship) correct? In my defence, this is in the material components. Spells cast without material components may vary (??). Edit: i am joking about the spiritual Medium being required for the spell to work : P

Comment: Oh no worry, like, it's not even *in* the errata. There's no way you'd know about it unless you had a very recent copy of the PHB or checked that single Q/A I linked. I'm just kinda sad stuff does get changed and yet isn't found in the errata documents/packets.

Comment: plus, I love your absurdum approach.  Rules as Fun, for the win!!!!!!